Navigate to LWC page from a custom button on an object using Lightning:UrlAddressable
I want to open a LWC page (a form) in a new page when clicking on a custom URL button on a standard object page. The issue is I don't know what the button URL should be, and how to properly wrap it using an Aura component.

What code should be added to the LWC?
How should the aura component look like?
What URL should be the input of the button?


Do you have checked this? - Navigate to a URL-Addressable Component
